# Check sheet by month

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub IMPORT_MSG()
    Dim strMonth As String
    Dim strSheet As String
    strSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    strMonth = Format(Date, ("mmmm" & "_yy"))
    If strSheet < strMonth Then
        MsgBox "test1"
    ElseIf strSheet >= strMonth Then
        MsgBox "test2"
    End if
End sub
```

I have 12 sheets names by month like (March_15, April_15) and so on. I have made this code to check if the active sheet is before this month to popup a messge1 other wise to show up the message2.
The problem is that it doesn’t work normal. The results I get are below:
March_15 give message2 instead if message1
April_15  give message1 (Normal)
May_15, September_15, oktomber_15 & November_15 give message2 (Normal)
June_15, july_15 , August_15 &  December_15 give message1 instead if message2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub IMPORT_MSG()
    Dim Dt$, i&: i = 1
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    While i <= 12
        Dic.Add MonthName(i), i: i = i + 1
    Wend
    Dt = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, WorksheetFunction.Search("_", ActiveSheet.Name) - 1)
    If Dic(Dt) < Month(Date) Then
        MsgBox "test1"
    Else
        MsgBox "test2"
    End If
End Sub
```